# A basic question about market jargon

Tags: terminology, jargon

What does it mean by DBR 4s of Jan4, 2037? I know the Jan4, 2037 is the maturity. How about DBR and 4s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBR = Deutschland Bundesrepublik

DBR 4 = German Government Bond with a coupon of 4%.